Can not access server via SSH, Permission Denied
I have recently set up a server on an AWS EC2 instance with Ubuntu 24.04. I am trying to change the configuration to authenticate via password but when I try to log in I get a 'Permission denied, please try again.' error message.
I have done the following:

Updated /etc/ssh/sshd_config so: PubkeyAuthentication no, and PasswordAuthentication yes
Created a new user that has been given sudo access.
Restarted the ssh service with sudo systemctl restart ssh
Checked the user isn't locked
Checked AllowUsers isn't set in the config
Triple checked the password is right (I can su to that user with no problem).

Here is the output from the attempted connection:
ssh -vvv username@18.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_9.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 18.xxx.xxx.xxx is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 18.xxx.xxx.xxx [18.xxx.xxx.xxx ] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 18.xxx.xxx.xxx :22 as 'username'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from 18.xxx.xxx.xxx 
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-s,kex-strict-s-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug3: kex_choose_conf: will use strict KEX ordering
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:zzSUWOxfnJ9mRowALRTDSqVH+jYFh5CQhMhJVn4j/wY
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from 18.xxx.xxx.xxx 
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '18.xxx.xxx.xxx ' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/localuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO
debug3: send packet: type 7
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension server-sig-algs
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension publickey-hostbound@openssh.com
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension ping@openssh.com
debug1: kex_ext_info_check_ver: ping@openssh.com=<0>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug3: kex_input_ext_info: extension server-sig-algs
debug1: kex_ext_info_client_parse: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256>
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.voOEBl7ytW/Listeners'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: agent contains no identities
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZcXd3HoA0S488gtDsGKvVP+p6yyaIyw6kxVmneraJpo
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ZcXd3HoA0S488gtDsGKvVP+p6yyaIyw6kxVmneraJpo
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /Users/localuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
username@18.xxx.xxx.xxx 's password: 
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: 
Permission denied, please try again.

I can't any other possible reason it should not be working. Any guideance would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Try ssh -vvv [...] when connecting to the server, it should print some useful debugging lines which should give an insight as to what's going on, then please add the output of the command to your question so that we can take look at it

Thanks @kos I have added the output to the original post.

I personally can't see anything wrong with that (maybe someone else will), however what about logs on the server? Can you run journalctl -n 50 --no-pager -xu ssh on the server right after a failied connection attempt (and add the output to the question)?

Are you connecting from a Windows client? If so, I wonder if there is a character encoding issue between the client terminal (PowerShell?) and the remote server. Are there non-ASCII characters in the password?
